# How can I dynamically add new icons to Android's main menu grid from Java?

Tags: android-manifest, android-intent, android

I have an application that I'd like to have multiple icons in the launcher's main menu grid but only under certain conditions. For instance, I want to show icon A and icon B but only if the phone is running Android 2.2 because icon B uses a Froyo feature, so I don't want icon B showing up if on a pre-Froyo device.

Is there a way in Java to programmatically add the main menu icon? I don't want it in the manifest file as this isn't flexible at run time... at least not as far as I am aware. This would allow me to either check for some functionality, API, user preference, or a flag in the app.

Comment: Could you just inflate the layout, select the ImageViews for the icons and set their visibility based on android.os.Build.VERSION?

Comment: @willytate: He's talking about Android's global app list.

Comment: ahh, disregard my comment then :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about declaring both activities in the manifest, but then enabling / disabling them as needed using [PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting()](https://bit.ly/fq6yuu)?

Good luck

Tom

Comment: Tom, that's a great suggestion. I'll try that. Ideally, I'd like to add items dynamically though since I have a few use cases that I think would benefit from this, but this should hopefully work for most of what I want to do.

Comment: Nice to hear that, Joel. Please don't forget to mark this answer as correct if it's what you were looking for...

Comment: That solution worked as long as I have the activity hard coded in the manifest. I'm going to keep looking around for options to make this dynamic, but for now, I can work with this.

Comment: Has anyone considered how Google implements "Directions & Navigation" shortcuts on the home screen?  When you select this item, it allows you to dynamically choose elements to the shortcut. This insinuates that they don't have hard coded items in their manifest for all possible combinations. Similarly, other shortcuts for bookmarks, contacts, Gmail labels, etc. all seem to be dynamic. Any thoughts on how they do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to change that at runtime.  You could either release two versions of the app, one for pre-froyo and one for after if they are sufficiently different, or check out this article on various ways to do [backward compatability](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) within a single app.